# how do I stop a sound?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am making an alarm so how can I stop the sound when I close the project ???? because the sound still plays when I close it, how to stop it ? I already put this but did not work :

```
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    //your code for stopping the sound
}
```

here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView img;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           MediaPlayer media = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.alarm);
            media.start();

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you put media.stop(); in the onStop() method

Comment: Instead of in onStop() you might want to use onDestroy()

Comment: yes, I have put both you told me but the sound still plays when I close.

Comment: @user2446251 : Don't use `getBaseContext()` unless you know what it is for. In an `Activity`, use `this` for a `Context`.

Comment: I like when these reputation 1 guys asks a question and never comes back to check answers... There should be a limit that you cant even ask a question when rep 1.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm using in my project is:

Declare instance of `Ringtone` in main activity

```
Ringtone ringtone;
```

**To start playing sound:**

```
ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse(ringUri));
ringtone.play();
```

Where ringUri is `uri` of ringtone or sound you want to play.

**To stop sound:**

```
ringtone.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the MediaPlayer media variable global and when the onStop fires you can stop it there:

```
private MediaPlayer media;

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    //your code for stopping the sound
    if( media != null && media.isPlaying()) {
        media.stop();
    }
}
```